# Access Oracle document cloud service from JET using REST Api

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, oracle-jet

Hope everybody is in good health and spirit.

I am trying to show oracle documents (folder with files) in to an Iframe using JET. for than I need to get a JSON response from REST api provided by oracle.
when we access the rest api using postman it returns the correct JSON output ([reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/documentcs_welcome/WCDRA/api-Applinks.html)).

But when I try to obtain the same using JSON Ajax call I get following error in browser console:

> jquery-3.1.0.js:9392 XMLHttpRequest cannot load link. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed access.

here is the code snipped :

```
self.getFolderDetails = function(){
     $.ajax({
        url: "testurl",
        type: "GET",
        userName: "<User name>",
        password: "<Password>",
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Authorization' : 'Basic <Auth Token>'
        },
        success: function (data) {
             parsedJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
             console.log('Response JSON Data-->  ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.log('Fail Response JSON Data-->  ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
 }
```

usually  in such scenario we apply CORS filter on exposed webservices. since these services created by Development cloud team, I can't do any changes from my end.

will really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Is your issue solved??

Answer (score 0):

As you said CORS would be required for such scenario as it is a security feature of browsers. That being said you can try some work around.

1. JSONP: This feature is again dependent on server side, so unless oracle provides it, you wont be able to do it.
2. Server Side Adapter: You can create a service of your own on your server side, that in tern call the the oracle service. You won't have Same Origin issues.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Document Cloud Service Doesn't Allow other domains to access information using REST until you assign the domain in "Cross Origin Domains" using admin actions from your Doc Cloud Service.

But for the testing on localhost you can use some plugins(**Allow-Control-Allow-Origin**) in Google chrome which allows you to access the same without throwing error.

Note: I hope you are aware about **accessToken**, **refresh Token**, and **role** things when you open Applink in Iframe.